# Update Panel or RadAjax Manager is not working for repeater

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, repeater, radiobuttonlist

I have tried almost all the available internet solutions  for this issue ,but none of them worked out.Please look into below code and let me know if any of you can help me to resolve the issue.The full page refresh is occurring on every click of radio button list.

telerik:RadScriptManager defined in master.master page

User Control Inside Master.Master.Page is given below

```
<style type="text/css">
        .rlbItem
        {
            float:left !important;
        }
        .RadListBox_Default .rlbGroup
    {         
        border: none !important;
    }

    </style>


<fieldset>







         <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="uxMainPanel">

              <asp:Label runat="server" Text="" Visible="false" id="uxCategoryId"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="" Visible="false" id="uxProjectId"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="" Visible="false" id="uxTemplateId"></asp:Label>  

              <asp:Label runat="server" Text="" Visible="false" id="uxPublicationId"></asp:Label>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="uxViewType" Visible="false" runat="server" />

            <table style="width:100%"><tr><td>

    <asp:Repeater ID="uxQuestionsList"   ClientIDMode="AutoID"    runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table class="white-table">
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:right"  class="tdLabel">
                        <asp:Label ID="uxQuestionId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProposalScreeningCategoryQuestionId")%>' Visible="false" />
                        <asp:Label ID="uxTemplateQuestionId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProposalScreeningTemplateCategoryQuestionId")%>' Visible="false" />
                         <asp:Label ID="uxQuestionText" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProposalScreeningCategoryQuestionName")%>' />:
                        <asp:Label ID="uxQuestionAnswerId" runat="server" Text="" Visible="false" />


                        <asp:Label ID="uxCollaborativeInstituteId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("institute_id")%>' Visible="false" />

</td><td class="tdField">


   <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server"   ID="up1s">

         <ContentTemplate>

   <div id="dvi">
                  <asp:RadioButtonList  ClientIDMode="AutoID"  RepeatDirection="Horizontal"    AutoPostBack="true"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="uxAnswerFlag_SelectedIndexChanged"       ID="uxAnswerFlag" runat="server">
                   <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                   <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>


               </asp:RadioButtonList>




               <asp:Panel ID="uxAnswerFlagReasonCheckBoxPanel"      runat="server">
                   <telerik:RadListBox RenderMode="Lightweight"    DataTextField="ProposalScreeningCategoryQuestionReasonName" DataValueField="ProposalScreeningCategoryQuestionReasonId" ID="uxAnswerFlagReasonCheckBox"  runat="server" CheckBoxes="true"  width="100%"
                />

               </asp:Panel>

               <asp:Panel ID="uxAnswerFlagReasonRadioButtonListPanel"   Visible="false"   runat="server">

                    <asp:RadioButtonList  RepeatDirection="Horizontal"     DataTextField="ProposalScreeningCategoryQuestionReasonName" DataValueField="ProposalScreeningCategoryQuestionReasonId" ID="uxAnswerFlagReasonRadioButtonList" runat="server" />
                   <br /><asp:Label ID="uxError" Visible="false"   ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="true" Text="Please choose an answer from above list" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                         </asp:Panel>
<appcontrols:AppRequiredFieldValidator ID="AppRequiredFieldValidator1"    ValidationGroup="save" runat="server" ControlToValidate="uxAnswerFlag"  />


 </div> </ContentTemplate> <Triggers><asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="uxAnswerFlag" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" /></Triggers></asp:UpdatePanel>    </td>
                </tr>






                <tr><td style="text-align:right"  class="tdLabel">Comments: <br /> <span class="gray">(Maximum 1500 characters)</span></td>
                    <td class="tdField" >
                        <Telerik:RadTextBox ID="uxAnswerText" runat="server"  Width="98%" Rows="8" onkeyup="if (this.value.length > 1500) { alert('Character limit has been reached!'); this.value = this.value.substr(0,1500); }" TextMode="MultiLine" />
                        <asp:Label ID="uxAnswerLabel" Visible="false" runat="server"  Width="98%" />
                        <br />

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <asp:Panel ID="uxActionByPanel" runat="server" Visible="false">
                <tr><td style="text-align:right" class="tdLabel">Action By:</td><td class="tdField"><asp:Label ID="uxActionBy" Visible="false" runat="server"  Width="98%" /></td></tr>
                </asp:Panel>
            </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>

</td></tr><tr><td align="center">

<asp:Button Text="Save" id="uxSave" CommandName="CallFromNestedUserControl"  ValidationGroup="save" CssClass="ButtonNormal" runat="server" />
  <asp:Button Text="Edit" id="uxEdit"    CausesValidation="false" CssClass="ButtonNormal" runat="server" />
         </td></tr>



            </table> 
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="uxSecondPanel">
        <p><b>There are no any Questions to be answered for this section.</b></p>
    </asp:Panel>
   <asp:HiddenField ID="uxSingleOutcomeCategoryHiddenField" Value="0" runat="server" />
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Remove** the `Triggers` collection of up1s. The update panel is in a data bound control, so the final ID of the radio button list will change for each row, it will never be exactly uxAnswerFlag.

You can also try setting the `ChildrenAsTriggers` property to `true`.

In general, such granularity is a bit difficult to achieve with MS AJAX in data bound controls, so you can look into AJAX-enabling the entire repeater.

Comment: Thanks for your answer..i have already tried by wrapping the repeater with updatepanel but it did not work out.Could you please elaborate your solution with code.